Accumulating values in polyline feature class using ArcGIS Pro
I'm using ArcGIS Pro 3.1
I have a road network where individual roads have been drawn such that when they intersect they overlay each other (A - C via B and A - E via B). In each road (e.g. row of the feature class) is a field that contains the number of vehicles at any one time. I would like to analyse this feature class such that I create a feature class that records the accumulated number of vehicles per segment of road.
This will result in a feature class that has a "vehicle accumulation" field that contains the summed values of intersecting vehicle volume. Whilst starting to figure this out I have taken the original data, split line by vertice and I am trying to figure out the logic for calculating the accumulation of values where they intersect. This will eventually be run on large datasets so codifying this process will be helpful.
Any tips?
The purpose is to enable the visualization of a map similar to the river accumulation map found here:


Trivial, BUT you need a destination point(s). With rivers they are outlets. What are yours.

This is for roads (the images was as close as I could find for the viz I need to make). The destination point would be the end of the road - should that be defined as a point?

Where is road end? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/466131/algorithm-for-recursive-network-optimization#466147
